# Book about a group of young students from around the world, who discover scientists performing cruel experiments on animals, and try to stop them

Tags: story-identification, books

I'm looking for a book. I can't remember the title or names, however, from what I can recollect, it was fiction, maybe sci-fi.

It was about a team or group of teen/young adults that ended up coming from different parts of the world to study in the Sahara/Africa. They discover that a lab or some scientists were experimenting on animals, and made them act super crazy and ended up changing their colors as well. It came down to the last two of the group stopping them. They had to survive and do all that jazz.

Comment: Welcome to the site. When did you read this book, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, can you recall any details about what the cover looked like?

Comment: Any other details you can add might help.  For example, what were the experiments?  In what way did the animals act crazy?  Can you remember clearly any specific scenes?  This is vaguely ringing a bell, but I can not quite place it....

Answer (score 3):

*Kalahari* (2015) by Jessica Khoury? It's the third book in her *Corpus* series but apparently it can be read as a standalone novel.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25431243-kalahari):

> **When an educational safari goes wrong, five teens find themselves stranded in the Kalahari Desert without a guide.** It’s up to Sarah, the daughter of zoologists, to keep them alive and lead them to safety, calling on survival know-how from years of growing up in remote and exotic locales. Battling dehydration, starvation and the pangs of first love, she does her best to hold it together, even as their circumstances grow increasingly desperate.
>
> But soon a terrifying encounter makes Sarah question everything she’s ever known about the natural world. **A silver lion, as though made of mercury, makes a vicious, unprovoked attack on the group.** After a narrow escape, they uncover the chilling truth behind the lion’s silver sheen: **a highly contagious and deadly virus that threatens to ravage the entire area**—and eliminate life as they know it.

Corpus is a shady company with equally shady experiments. Several reviewed (such as [this one](https://ggcmagazine.com/kalahari-by-jessica-khoury/)) mention "crazy silver animals" which would match the "animals change color and go crazy" recollection. Apparently the cure comes from a species of bees.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book teens africa discover experiment animals site:goodreads.com/book`.